# What's causing NoSuchMethodError and NoClassDefFoundError?

Tags: java, classpath, noclassdeffounderror, nosuchmethoderror

When I run test.class I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: ml.Temp.<init>(Ljava/lang/String;II)V
    at test.main(test.java:11)
```

And here is the code for test.java

```
import java.io.*;
import ml.*;

class test
{
        public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException
        {
                String filename = "input";

                Temp id = new Temp(filename, 6, 100);
                    id.someFunction();          
         }
}
```

Essentially I have a jar file containing Temp.class (Temp is a library file that I wrote and which is under the ml package). Temp has a constructor which takes these three arguments and a public someFunction.

Not sure if this helps, but I included the classpath of the jar file during the compilation. When I include the classpath of the jar file during running of test.class I get the following

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: test
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: test
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:321)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
Could not find the main class: test. Program will exit.
```

EDIT:

If it helps I compiled as follows (ml.jar and test.java are in the same directory)

```
javac -cp ml.jar test.java
```

Comment: How are you building / running this?

Comment: In case of the first error, I just did a java test. I get the second error if I do a java -cp "ml.jar" test

Answer (score 2):

you should run the command `java -cp <path-to-ml.jar> test` from the path in which `test.class` resides.

**EDIT**

The `NoSuchMethodError` indicates that in line 11 of class `test` you're trying to use a constructor of `ml.ID3` (not `Temp`!) with a signature (`String, int, int`) that doesn't exist. It doesn't mean it's not in the classpath because that would result in `NoClassDefFoundError`.

On the other hand, the `NoClassDefFoundError: test` means that `test` is not in your clsspath anymore. Adding the jar to the classpath, if this all you've really done to get the `NoClassDefFoundError: test`, **cannot** cause `test` to disappear from your classpath... So it's more likely that you've done some other inadvertent action.

**EDIT 2**

Maybe that constructor exists in the `ID3` used in your development environment but it evidently doesn't exist in your runtime environment. If it's a 3rd party jat, might happen you have two versions of that jar, one used in dev and the other in runtime. Or maybe even both appear in your runtime environment but the one that lacks that constructor tool precedence.

Comment: Yes, I did run it from where the test.class resides. Or do you by any chance mean Temp.class ?

Comment: No. Temp.class should be in the jar referenced by `path-to-ml.jar`.

Comment: Yes, in that case - I do run it from the same path as test.class

Comment: I edited my answer to add explanation that might direct you to further investigation.

Comment: well ID3 is the same as Temp (I usually change class names before putting code out in a forum - but did not remove it in the error). And ID3 does have a constructor with that same signature (which is why I am confused).

Comment: OK, added another possibility in the answer :). Hope it'll help.

Answer (score 1):

Its difficult to tell you exactly what happened without the source code but it looks like your library and the project which is using it, are out of synch. Have you changed the signatures of any methods in your library/project? I would recommend to recompile everything and then check if the class `test` is using the latest version of the library you have recompiled as well as if its declared `public`.

More useful information on how to read `NoSuchMethodError` etc can be found in a great article here: http://www.cubrid.org/blog/dev-platform/understanding-jvm-internals/

Answer (score 1):

I am going to pretend to be you and go through the whole process:

1 - The Library. I am in a directory called, say, `workspace`. Inside it, I have created a directory called `ml`. 
Inside the `ml` directory I have created a new file called `Temp.java` which, for the sake of example, contains the following:

```
package ml;

public class Temp
{
    public Temp(String filename, int arg1, int arg2)
    {
        //do something
    }

    public void someFunction()
    {
        //do something else
        System.out.println("look left!");
    }
}
```

I am now going to compile the library class and create a library jar.
First I compile by running

```
javac ./Temp.java
```

inside the `ml` directory. Then I jar the library by going one directory up to the `workspace` directory and running:

```
jar cf ml.jar ml/
```

2 - The Program. I now create the `Test.java` file inside the `workspace` directory. The file contains the following:

```
import java.io.*;
import ml.*;

public class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException
    {
        String filename = "input";

        Temp id = new Temp(filename, 6, 100);
        id.someFunction();
    }
}
```

3 - The Result. I now proceed to compile and run my test program. Inside the `workspace` directory I run:

```
javac -cp ./:ml.jar ./Test.java
```

I can finally run the program by running the following command inside the `workspace` directory:

```
java -cp ./:ml.jar Test
```

Which would show the output:

```
look left!
```

I hope this helps.